# lines are mixed up when running emacs remotely

Tags: ssh, remote

When I ssh onto a remote server, and then open emacs on that server, and attempt to edit, I often experience many issues with the display.

For example, when I move my cursor around the file using C-l or C-v, lines often get mixed up and display improperly. If I have multiple files open, moving around in one file causes lines to move around. This is a completely graphical issue and if i background and resume emacs, everything goes back to normal.

I've attached two screenshots, showing emacs before I hit C-l a couple of times, and showing the window after I hit C-l a couple of times. As you can see, the code afterwards is displayed improperly, and the bounday between the two files is also screwed up.

What is the cause of this, and how can it be fixed?

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: That's a curious one. Perhaps your terminal's capabilities are being incorrectly identified? Which terminal emulator do you use? What is your `TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: My term is 'xterm-256color'

Comment: And your terminal emulator is...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When i type echo $TERM, i get xterm-256color. Some more detail is that this graphical glitch also happens sometimes when i search, and i think there are some answered questions about that issue so I will try out those solutions.

Comment: The terminal emulator is the program which provides the window that you're typing into (terminals are physical devices; the window is a virtual one). What is the name of the program? How do you open your terminal window? Maybe tell us your OS as well?

Comment: Yes. I am on GNOME Terminal 3.20 on Ubuntu 17.04. I have also experienced the problem on xfce4-terminal on archlinux. Furthermore, a friend I talked to mentioned they have the same problem, on their macbook-pro, although I'm not sure of their terminal

Comment: That's good information, and *seems* to point the finger at the remote system. I don't know enough to make a confident guess at what's going wrong, though. I certainly haven't experienced issues when specifying `xterm-256color` for the Ubuntu Terminal, so I feel that should be fine. Bad termcap/terminfo databases on the remote system might be a possibility. I don't know for sure if this is sane, but you might try copying a known good `xterm-256color` file into `~/.terminfo/x/xterm-256color` on the remote system. On my Ubuntu machine that file lives in `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`.